# Golang, nil pointer dereference or invalid memory address

Tags: http, go, concurrency

my code works perfectly until I want to scale it using many concurrent calls. It works by asking the client a Get request.

This is what I'm getting:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x400da9]

goroutine 125 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x697480, 0x850d13)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0xf5
main.concurrent(0x25e5)
    /home/maker/go/src/GoBot/GoBot.go:19 +0x1a9
created by main.main
    /home/maker/go/src/GoBot/GoBot.go:51 +0x224
```

I think I'm not properly handling the error and when making a lot of requests it crashes.

```
func concurrent(n uint64) {
    for i := n; i < n+11; i++ {
            member,  err := s.GetUser(i)
            output <- fmt.Sprint(member.Username) //This is line 19 that triggers the error
            if err != nil && member != nil {
              continue
           }
     }
defer wg.Done()
}
```

How can I solve this?
References for s.GetUser here:
https://github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud/blob/master/soundcloud.go#L274

Comment: You're using `member` on line 19 even when there's an error returned from `GetUser`. It doesn't seem related to concurrency -- perhaps you're seeing it now just because your concurrent version makes more calls to `GetUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you could prevent the panic by checking the return value of `GetUser` which you're currently ignoring;

```
        member,  err := s.GetUser(i)
        if err != nil {
           // handle error
        }
        if member != nil { // prevents the panic attempting to access Username on nil instance of user/member
             output <- fmt.Sprint(member.Username) //This is line 19 that triggers the error
            if err != nil && member != nil {
              continue
           }
       }
```

Beyond that, what is `GetUser` doing? If it's making an HTTP GET, then typically the application would block until it returns, meaning chances are, if you check your error, there will be one like an HTTP 404, 403, 500 ect.

If the call to `GetUser` were concurrent, then you could run into an issue where the code below attempts to access the `member.Username` before `GetUser` has returned causing the `nil` panic but I don't see how that could happen since you have no goroutine there. It should just be a simple blocking call. If you find the above suggestion doesn't lead you to the root cause of your problem, then edit your question with the results from `GetUser` and it's implementation and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Actually, I'm making the function into goroutines. Is there a better way to do it or by just checking this it should solve it? @evanmcdonnal

Comment: @Juanvulcano I would assume you're calling `concurrent` in a go routine like `go concurrent(10)`, you have no goroutines within `concurrent` so within that scope there is no concurrency. That being said, just the check will probably do it for you, I'd be surprised if the root cause isn't a failure in `GetUser`

Comment: I'm using a for loop. https://play.golang.org/p/WyjoLFzCVW Am I doing it wrong? @evanmcdonnal

Comment: I implemented your code, it still fails. What could it be?